# How to add interactive UIView (e.g. countdown timer) in a CoreVideo live streaming session

Tags: swift, core-video

I am following a sample swift code that initiates a Facebook live streaming session from iPhone:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    liveButton.layer.cornerRadius = 15

    session = VCSimpleSession(videoSize: CGSize(width: 1280, height: 720), frameRate: 30, bitrate: 4000000, useInterfaceOrientation: false)
    contentView.addSubview(session.previewView)
    session.previewView.frame = contentView.bounds
    session.delegate = self
}

func startFBLive() {
    if FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil {
        FBLiveAPI.shared.startLive(privacy: livePrivacy) { result in
            guard let streamUrlString = (result as? NSDictionary)?.value(forKey: "stream_url") as? String else {
                return
            }
            let streamUrl = URL(string: streamUrlString)

            guard let lastPathComponent = streamUrl?.lastPathComponent,
                let query = streamUrl?.query else {
                    return
            }

            self.session.startRtmpSession(
                withURL: "rtmp://rtmp-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/",
                andStreamKey: "\(lastPathComponent)?\(query)"
            )

            self.livePrivacyControl.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }
    } else {
        fbLogin()
    }
}
```

This code will stream camera video feed to Facebook correctly.

However, how should I overlay a UIView, e.g. a countdown text ontop of the camera feed? I did not mean showing the UIView locally on the phone, I meant overlaying the UIView into the video feed so that the UIView gets streamed into Facebook Live stream and will be visible by other live stream viewers on other devices.

I can see that VCSimpleSession has this method:

```
addPixelBufferSource: (UIImage*) image
                     withRect: (CGRect) rect;
```

But this is probably not what I want since I need to add a countdown text...Any ideas?

Comment: Check this link out . https://github.com/rsrbk/SRCountdownTimer - Hope it helps.

Comment: @mkto
Hello, I'm currently working on a live-streaming app (using AVFoundation and amazon IVS broadcast SDK), and I'm trying to add some UIViews (or custom UIimages) onto the stream. I'm trying to add them using CMSampleBuffer in `captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection)` method (still not sure if it's the right way or not), but I'm kinda stuck now... Were you able to add some UIViews onto the stream? If so, how did you achieve it?

Comment: @Yuuu I don't really remember what I did. But as commented on another thread below I had success overlaying image following this: https://github.com/kciter/FBLiveAPISample-iOS. You can give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy without having access to VCSimpleSession or the FBAPI (can you link to the tutorial? or a sample project)

From some research it seems VCSimpleSession has previewLayer from the camera feed.

So you could create a label, add it to the camera preview layer and update it at some interval (here each second). See code below:

```
private var elapsedTime : TimeInterval = 0.0
private var timer: Timer?
private var timerLabel: UILabel!


private func startTimer() {
    guard timer == nil else { return }
    session.previewLayer.layer.addSublayer(timerLabel.layer)
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc private func updateTimer() {
    elapsedTime += 1
    let minutes = Int(elapsedTime / 60)
    let seconds = Int(elapsedTime.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 60))

    timerLabel.text = String.init(format:"%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)

}

private func stopTimer(){
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. You misunderstood my question too.

Comment: I understand what you need (display **and** broadcast the timer to everyone) but it's hard to go further without having access to the APIs and code. @mkto

Comment: This is a sample code I am looking at, I manage to overlay AND broadcast static image, but not sure about animated UIView etc. https://github.com/kciter/FBLiveAPISample-iOS

Answer (score -2):

When start live streaming session then

- Add UIView (Countdown View) with UILabel on your parent view.
- UILabel text change with timer.
- Must be your UIView (Countdown view) with transparent background.

May be your problem will be solve.

[image]

Comment: Hmm thats not what I meant. I meant I want to overlay something onto the camera video feed so that the UIView gets streamed onto Facebook Live Stream.

Comment: When you add your view on your parent view the view like this please check this sample image which is uploaded.

Comment: That's not what I need - I need the ability to overlay UIViews/text/animations on top of the camera feed so that the UIViews/text/animations GETS STREAMED into the Facebook server and every Facebook audience gets to see the UIViews/text/animations on Facebook page. addPixelBufferSource: (UIImage*) image method allow me to add static image INTO the stream, but I wonder what should I do for an animated countdown UIView.